# Is it possible to have conditionals in /etc/rc.local?

Tags: shell-script, shell, test, syntax, rc

Is it possible to have a conditional within `/etc/rc.local`?
I've checked many Q&As and most people suggest running `chmod +x` on it, but my problem is different. It actually *does* work for me without conditionals, but doesn't otherwise.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -e /usr/src/an-existing-file ]]
then
    echo "seen" >> /etc/rclocalmadethis
fi
```

Here's the weird error I see when I run `systemctl status rc-local.service`:

```sh
rc.local[481]: /etc/rc.local: 3: /etc/rc.local: [[: not found
```

And here's my `rc.local` in the exact same location `ls -lah /etc/`:

```sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    292 Sep 19 09:13 rc.local
```

I'm on Debian 10 Standard.

Comment: As a side note: `-e` checks for the existence of ANY file type, you can run: `info test` to get more information on tests.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `[[ ... ]]` syntax isn't valid for `/bin/sh`.  Try:

```bsh
if [ -e /usr/src/an-existing-file ]
then
    echo "seen" >> /etc/rclocalmadethis
fi
```

Note that sometimes it works because `/bin/sh -> /bin/bash` or some other shell that supports that syntax, but you can't depend on that being the case (as you see here).

You can run `ls -l /bin/sh` to get to know this info for instance:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 18  2019 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Answer (score 3):

`[[` is a bash feature not available in `sh`:

```
root@d4b4b6325f2a:/# type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
root@d4b4b6325f2a:/# sh
# type [[
[[: not found
```

Answer (score -1):

In such circumstances, I would probably look at the test command.

```
/usr/bin/test -e /usr/src/an-existing-file && /bin/echo "seen" >> /etc/rclocalmadethis
```

Comment: Well, yes, that bypasses the issue of `[[` vs. `[`, but doesn't tell why the code they tried here didn't work. In any case, `test` and `echo` are standard utilities, there's no need to write the full paths, just `test -e ... && echo ... ` would do. Or `if test -e ...; then echo ...; fi`